# Why is the move constructor not invoked here when the function parameter takes an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

In my mind these are the things that should be happening to this program
 1. Int i(i) -> Create a new Int object, call the copy ctor.
 2. print(std::move(i)) -> Create an Rvalue reference out of i and then assign it to a, and in doing so call the move ctor.
 3. cout "print 1".
 4. cout "main func -1", because the move ctor pillaged its resource.

So my expectation of the output is:

> ctor
>   move ctor
>   print 1
>   main func -1

But, the move ctor is never called.
And this is the output that is actually seen:

> ctor
>   print 2
>   main func 2

```
class Int {  
 public:  
  Int(int i) : i_(i) { std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl; }  
  Int(const Int& other) {  
    std::cout << "copy ctor " << std::endl;  
    i_ = other.i_;  
  }  

  Int(Int&& other) {  
    std::cout << "move ctor " << std::endl;  
    i_ = other.i_;  
    // Pillage the other's resource by setting its value to -1.
    other.i_ = -1;   
  }  
  int i_;   
};  

void print(Int&& a) { std::cout << "print " << a.i_ << std::endl; }  

int main() {  
  Int i(1);  
  print(std::move(i));  
  std::cout << "main func " << i.i_ << std::endl;  
}
```

Why is that ?

Comment: `void print(Int&& a); print(std::move(i))` nothing here constructs a new object. If you want to get a new instance of `Int`, then declare `void print(Int a);`.

Comment: `print` receives a reference to the original object.

Comment: An rvalue reference still is a reference. As long as you do not construct a value object from...